# What does this bar notation mean?

Tags: matrices, notation

I have a problem in which I need to solve for $x$ in the question (in image) below, but I don't even understand it. Is this suppose to be a matrix?
$$\begin{vmatrix}\ln(2x+1)&2-\ln x\\1&1\end{vmatrix}=0$$

Comment: I think a picture or rendering it in LaTeX would prove more useful, because the bit you pasted renders as nonsense for me.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I've added a picture!

Comment: This looks like the determinant of a $2 \times 2$ matrix by my eye.

Answer (score 1):

The bar notation means taking the determinant of the matrix enclosed. This is a shorthand for $\det M$.

Answer (score 0):

The bar notation is used to indicate the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) of a matrix. It converts a matrix into a scalar. For example,
$$\begin{align}\begin{vmatrix} a & b\\c & d \end{vmatrix}=ad - bc \end{align}$$
Other common notations are $\det A$ and $\det (A)$.

In particular, for your case, the mentioned determinant becomes
$$\begin{align}\begin{vmatrix} \ln (2x+1) & 2-\ln x\\1 & 1 \end{vmatrix}=\ln (2x+1)-2+\ln x = \ln (2x^2+x)-2 \end{align}$$

Hope this helps :)